# Text found in Notepad++ using RegEx extends too far

Tags: notepad++, regex

Let's assume the following text

```
a=1
b=2
x=1
---------
a=1
b=3
c=3
x=2
---------
a=2
b=5
x=3
... and so on, many blocks starting with a=, ending with x= and something in between
```

I would like to replace the x value with 0 for all blocks where a=1. For this, I search for the following

```
^(a=1$.*?x=).*$
```

and replace it with

```
\10
```

The problem is, that the first occurence already extends from the first a=1 to the last x=3. It does not stop at the first occurence of x (i.e. x=1)

How can I make it select only from the first a to the x that goes along with this a (i.e. only the first 3 lines, then the 4 lines of the next block, and so on)?

Answer (score 1):

I was almost there... just forgot to make the last .* lazy as well. So the correct search string is

```
^(a=1$.*?x=).*?$
```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^a=1$(?:(?!^a=).)+x=\K\d+`
- Replace with: `0`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
a=1                 # literally a=1
$                   # end of line
       # Tempered Greedy Token
(?:                 # non capture group
    (?!             # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't:
        ^a=           # a line that begins with a=
    )               # end lookahead
    .               # any character
)+                  # end group may appear 1 or more times
x=                  # literally x=
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
\d+                 # 1 or more digitss
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the interesting solution. There is definitely more than one way to tackle this problem :-)

Comment: @Thomas: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- In the Find what box, enter: `(^a=1$.*?x=)(\d+)`
- In the Replace with box: `${1}0`

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Sorry, but that is not entirely correct, either. It replaces the x by a 0, not the text following x=

Comment: @Thomas you wrote on the OP: "I would like to replace the x value with 0 for all blocks where a=1". Has that changed? or are you replaceing the value of x?

Comment: @Thomas See edit.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are asking for:

Insert into "Find What:"
`(a=1[^x]*x=)([0-9])`

Insert into "Replace With:" `\10`

I have tested this with the data given and using the following online tool to build the regex query - https://regex101.com/